# how to differentiate between color and value in send cellchanged signal

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtablewidget

There is a table with some values in it. what I am trying to do is to capture changes of the table content and save them inside a SQLite database. so I connected table to `cellChanged` and `itemSelectionChanged` signals. when I try to change some cells content, it will check it to verify it does not contain letters, and it's a number. so if after changing the cell, it has letters inside, it will try to rechange the content to its previous value.
I also have a search toolbar to search in table for some keyword. what the search toolbar does, is to colorize the cells that matching that specific keyword. but in doing so, it emits `cellChanged` signal and not `cellSelectionChanged` signal. that causes an error (myapp object has no attribute previous_value), because I haven't selected any cell yet. But if I select a cell and then start seeking, writing anything inside search box will change the content of every cell, because it is triggering `cellChanged` signal. my question is how to differentiate between color and text changes in `cellChanged` function. thank you in advance.
here is the sample code:(python 3.7.4, pyqt5 5.13.0)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys
class myapp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
        for i in range(5):
            for j in range(5):
                item=QTableWidgetItem("cell["+str(i) + ","+ str(j) + "]")
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i,j,item)
        self.tableWidget.cellChanged.connect(self.on_tablewidget_cell_changed)
        self.tableWidget.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.on_tablewidget_item_selection_changed)

        self.search_entry = QLineEdit()
        self.search_entry.textChanged.connect(self.seek)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.search_entry)
        self.setLayout(layout)
    def on_tablewidget_cell_changed(self,row,col):
        value = self.tableWidget.item(row,col).text()
        if not self.check_numeric(value):
            self.tableWidget.item(row,col).setText(self.previous_value)
    def on_tablewidget_item_selection_changed(self):
        row = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
        col = self.tableWidget.currentColumn()
        self.previous_value = self.tableWidget.item(row,col).text()
    def seek(self):
        keyword = self.search_entry.text()
        items = self.tableWidget.findItems(keyword, Qt.MatchContains)
        for item in items:
            item.setBackground(Qt.red)

    def check_numeric(self,value):
        value = value.strip()
        tmp = "".join([i for i in value if i in "0123456789"])
        return(len(value) == len(tmp))


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = myapp()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of capturing `cellChanged` signals to check if the user input is valid, you could set an item delegate for the table widget, and check the user input in there before setting the model data. For example:

```
class IntItemDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def setModelData(self, editor, item_model, model_index):
        # only update the model data if the user input consists of digits only.
        text = editor.text()
        if self.check_numeric(text):
            item_model.setData(model_index, text)

    def check_numeric(self, value):
        return value.isdecimal()


class myapp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
        for i in range(5):
            for j in range(5):
                item=QTableWidgetItem("cell["+str(i) + ","+ str(j) + "]")
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i,j,item)

        # set a custom item delegate which will take care of checking the user input
        self.tableWidget.setItemDelegate( IntItemDelegate())

        self.search_entry = QLineEdit()
        self.search_entry.textChanged.connect(self.seek)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.search_entry)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def seek(self):
        keyword = self.search_entry.text()
        items = self.tableWidget.findItems(keyword, Qt.MatchContains)
        for item in items:
            item.setBackground(Qt.red)
```

Comment: thank you @Heike , you didn't answer my question, But you actually solved my problem. thank you again

Comment: is there any way to differentiate between color and text in cellChanged?